# Sql Server 2008 Nesting Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

Is there a general best practice on whether or not to use nested views?  Is there a performance hit when using nested views?  Is there a best practice that says there really isn't a performance hit until you go 4 or more layers deep?

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm struggling with whether or not to use them.  It is not unusual to get a report request of which the only way I can get access to that information is by joining 20 or more tables together.  Fields are not returned from all the tables but are needed to select the correct data.  In this case I like nesting the views and reusing the lower level views for other reports because if a change to the logic is needed I just update one view and all reports are updated.  Many of the tables I work with contain millions and millions of records.

However perhaps this is not a good practice.  Do you mind sharing your thoughts on this?

Comment: Do the views do aggregations? Are you joining the same base table to itself? Look at the execution plan and see if you are getting sub optimal plans.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a "nested view"?  I'm only familiar with the terminology as: inline view (AKA derived table), non-materialized and materialized views (AKA indexed views in SQL Server).

Comment: @OMG - I took it to mean Views that reference other Views which reference other Views...

Comment: @Martin: Layering views? That is bad...  /me waves finger at Martin, and I suppose the OP

Comment: Yes that is what I meant... views referencing other views.  Right now I am reviewing execution plans and I'm going to back off from nesting views and looking at what indexed views might be able to help with just one layer deep.

Answer (score 15):

I would avoid this at all costs. First once you nest views they cannot be indexed. Next, since they have to fully materialize the underlying views to get to the next layer. So you could be materializing multi-millions of records to get an end result of 5 records. We very nearly lost a multimillion dollar client because performance was so abysmal when our devs did this on one database (not a database I had input into the design of).

Finally I have found that these sorts of layers are much, much harder to maintain when you need to make a change. It's no fun to track through 12 layers of views to find the one you need to fix. We also ran into an issue because devs found it easier just to add another layer than fix the underlying layers and then were trying to access too many tables in one query and way too many of those tables were the same multi-million record table being accessed 7 or 8 times in different layers of the views.

There is no circumstance where I would allow more than one layer in a view in a database I manage and I'd be angry if you did that.

Comment: +1 SQL is a circumstance where repeating yourself to avoid nesting views is appropriate.

Comment: The optimizer can make use of indices in nested views unless the view logic is complicated and obscures the index. Indexed views present a different set of issues, but for ordinary views performing simple joins, nesting does NOT prevent the optimizer from using an index.

Comment: I mean you can't create indexes on the views not that they can't use underlying indexes. However, you can very quickly get to the point where the optimizer can't figure out how to handle this efficently. Not only that they very quickly become an unmaintainable mess. It is a SQL antipattern that shoud be avoided if possible and it is almost always possible.

Comment: Views can be used to capture join relationships that are repeatedly needed at multiple levels. For example, I have a Market table. Every market belongs to a sector, so I also have a Sector table, and the Market table has a SectorId with appropriate foreign key. Every sector belongs to a MacroSector, so I also have a MacroSector table,  and the Sector table has a MacroSectorId with appropriate foreign key. Now, if I told you that many things that use the market will also need the sector and macro sector, are you really going to rewrite the same join relationship dozens of times? *That's* a mess

Comment: And views can cause the database to do extra work which is far more important than a dev having to write a couple of joins. Views are not a good practice if you nest them. You can get into serious trouble.

Answer (score 7):

Other options to consider:
**Indexed Views**  -- Can be dangerous to use if not used correctly but the performance gains can be amazing.

**Analytics** -- such as grouping sets

**procedures & temp tables** -- Get the data you need via procedure write it out to temp tables select from temp tables.

Overall I don't like the performance hit of view on view on view or nested views.

Generally you can generate one view using the correct joins between tables which contains all the information your after and filter out the data using criteria.

Comment: Question about indexed views.  Does the view need to be explicitly specified or will the optimizer chose an indexed view even if you are going to some base tables but in the execution path it determines the view to be better.

Comment: So I found this answer  The view does not need to be referenced directly in the query for the optimizer to use it in the query execution plan.

Comment: @user - Depens on version. This only happens in Enterprise and Developer edition otherwise you need to reference the view explicitly and use the `noexpand` hint.